# What is the fiber class of a fibred surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $\Pi:X\to S$ be a fibred surface, i.e., $X,B$ are integral regular complete schemes of respective dimensions 2 and 1.

Let $\operatorname{Num}(X)$ be the quotient of $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ by the subgroup consisting of iso classes of invertible sheaves numerically equivalent to $0$.

> **Claim**: The image in $\operatorname{Num}(X)$ of a closed fiber $X_b \hookrightarrow X$ of $\Pi$ is independent of $b\in B(k)$.

I struggle to see why the claim is true even knowing that the numerically equivalent to zero divisors are the ones with intersection number zero with any divisor.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How much do you know about divisors on your surface overall? The basic idea should be that every divisor is linearly (hence numerically) equivalent to a linear combination of fibers and sections. A fixed fiber intersects all other fibers trivially, and has intersection number $1$ with all sections.

Comment: Many thanks @TabesBridges for your answer. I admit that I  don’t know much about divisors on the surface and a detailed answer would  be of very much help.